# Iterating through a HashSet using a for loop

Tags: java, string, for-loop, iteration, hashset

I have a HashSet that I would like to iterate through a for loop and display its contents but I don't know how to make it work. I can't seem to find a way to access an element of a certain index(i) of a HashSet. Is there a way to do this?

I have the following (non-compiling) code as my basis of what I want to achieve:

```
    public void postNumbers(HashSet<String> uniqueNumbers)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < uniqueNumbers.size(); i++)
        {
            System.out.println(uniqueNumbers(i));
        }
    }
```

I'd like to replace the System.out.println portion of the code (specifically uniqueNumbers(i)) but I don't know how to approach it

Comment: Not sure it's relevant to your question, but if you need a `Set` that preserves *insertion* order use a `LinkedHashSet`. Regardless, you should not program to the `HashSet` concrete type but instead to the `Set` interface.

Answer (score 3):

Sets don't have indexes, so your approach for traversing its elements won't work. Better use an enhanced for loop, like this:

```
for (String number : uniqueNumbers) {
    System.out.println(number);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is the solution I was looking for. Appreciate the help!

Comment: @KayleSmith my pleasure! If this post solved your question, please accept it, just click on the check mark to its left :)

Answer (score 0):

`HashSet` does not order its elements, thus referring to specific index does not work. To loop through elements in a `HashSet`, use for loop as following:

```
public void postNumbers(HashSet<String> uniqueNumbers)
{
    for (String n : uniqueNumbers)
    {
        System.out.println(n);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the help! This is exactly what I was looking for